# Matching Double String, how do I only match with 1 result?

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm able to match the string I need for regex but it is matching twice.

https://regex101.com/r/KmgGwS/7

```
if ( $_.PSPath -match ("(?<=\::)(.*?)(?=\\)+")) {
  $matches.Values
}
```

For example, the input string is something like:

```
'Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\Certificate::CurrentUser\Root\A43489159A520F0D93D032CCAF37E7FE20A8B419'
```

It expect it to get:

```
CurrentUser
```

With the current code, it gets that string *twice*:

```
CurrentUser
CurrentUser
```

Comment: doesn't `"(?<=\::)(.*?)(?=\\)+"` become `(?<=\::)(.*?)(?=\)+` to the regex engine ? This will produce an engine error...

Comment: @sln: In PowerShell, the backtick (`\``) is used as the escape character in double-quoted string literals; `\ ` characters are used verbatim - see [`about_Quoting_Rules`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're seeing is the match value and the
group 1 value. Both of which contain the same thing.

If you want to see only a single value, remove the capture group.

```
 (?<= :: )
 .*? 
 (?= \\ )
```

Or, like this `(?<=::).*?(?=\\)`

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**

```
$Matches[0]
```

contains what your regex matched *overall*, `$Matches[1]` contains what the 1st (and only) capture group (parenthesized sub-expression, `(...)`) matched - in your case, both values happen to be the same.

Unless you need to explicitly *enumerate* the overall match as well as capture-group matches, don't use `$Matches.Value`.

To enumerate capture-group values *only*, i.e. to enumerate all matches *except* the overall match, use:

```
# Enumerate all matches except the overall one (key 0)
$Matches.GetEnumerator().Where({ $_.Key -as [int] -ne 0 }).Value
```

---

**The [automatic `$Matches` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables#matches), in which PowerShell reflects the results of the most recent `-match` operation<sup>[1]</sup>, is a *hashtable* ([`System.Collections.Hashtable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable))**:

- Entry `0` (`$Matches[0]`) contains what the regex matched *in full*.
- All other entries, if any, contain the *substrings* that *capture groups* (parenthesized subexpressions, `(...)`) matched, with entry `1` representing the 1st capture group's match, `2` the 2nd, and so on.

  - If you use *named* capture groups (e.g. `(?<foo>...)`, the entries use that name (e.g., `$Matches['foo']` or, alternatively, `$Matches.foo`).
  - If you use *non-capturing* groups (`(?:...)`), they result in *no* entry in `$Matches`.
  - (Similarly, [look-around assertions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) - `(?<=...)`, `(?<!...)`, `(?=...)`, and `(?!...)` - do *not* result in entries.)

---

As for **what you tried**:

`$Matches.Values` outputs a *collection* of the values of *all* entries in the hashtable, meaning the overall match (entry `0`) as well as any capture-group matches.

Since your regex contains a capture group that effectively captures the same as the regex *as a whole*, `(.*?)`, `$Matches.Values` outputs a collection of values that is the equivalent of array 
`'CurrentUser', 'CurrentUser'`, which, when output to the console, yields the result shown in the question.

Note that if you regex happens not to contain any capture groups, as suggested in [sln's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57549093/45375), `$Matches.Values` may *appear* to return a *single string*, but in reality it returns an [`ICollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.icollection) instance that just happens to have only *one* element.

Now, that distinction between a single-element collection and a scalar may often be irrelevant in PowerShell, but it's something to be aware of, because there are cases where it matters.

---

<sup>[1] **Caveats**:

* If the regex didn't match at all, `$Matches` isn't updated, so the previous value may linger.

* If the LHS of `-match` is an *array* (collection), `-match` acts as a *filter*, and `$Matches` isn't updated.
Note that `$Matches` is also set in the branch handlers of a [`switch -Regex` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch).</sup>

Comment: i actually do enumerate and capture the group match in an array. Hence, I'm using match.values.

Comment: @123testing123: Then you're getting exactly what you're asking for: the value of the overall regex match in entry `0` and the value of capture group `1`, which happen to be the same in your case. So, why does the - expected - result surprise you, and why did you accept an answer that advises you to not use a capture group?

Comment: @123testing123 are you assigning the result back to `$Matches`? That's not going to work. Just grab `$matches[1]`

Comment: From the previous questions from @123testing123, I suspect that the input (`$_.PSPath`) is **not a single string value** but an array of strings (lines).

Comment: @iRon: But if the LHS of a `-match` operation is an _array_ (an enumerable), `-match` acts as a filter, and `$Matches` isn't populated at all; also, the provider-supplied `.PSPath` property is a single string in all cases that I'm aware of.