# Is it possible to get match position using `switch -regex`

Tags: regex, powershell, switch-statement

`Select-String -Pattern` returns the location of each match. For example:

```
$s = 'abcxyzabc' | Select-String -Pattern 'abc(?<x>.*)abc'
$s.Matches[0].Groups | Select-Object Name, Value, Index, Length
```

gives:

```
Name Value     Index Length
---- -----     ----- ------
0    abcxyzabc     0      9
x    xyz           3      3
```

where `Index` and `Length` specifies the location of each match.

However, I can't find how to get the location of each match when using `switch -regex`. For example:

```
switch -regex ('abcxyzabc') {
    'abc(?<x>.*)abc' {
        $matches
    }
}
```

gives:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
x                              xyz
0                              abcxyzabc
```

I can't find anything like `Index` and `Length` to get the match location in `$matches`.

I also checked that the type of `Matches` returned by `Select-String -Pattern` is `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match[]`, while the type of `$matches` in `switch -regex` is `System.Collections.Hashtable`.

Did I miss anything or `switch -regex` is not supposed to give the location of each match?

Comment: Powershell notwithstanding. In computer programming languages, a switch statement is a type of selection control mechanism used to allow the value of a variable or expression to change the control flow of program execution via search and map. Hence, boolean, not string. Just like a simple if/then. Switch statements come in two main variants: a structured and unstructured switch.

Comment: As  `mklement0`, points out, just skip the switch statement altogether. `([regex]::Match('abcxyzabc', 'abc(?<x>.*)abc')).Groups | Select-Object Name, Value, Index, Length`, well, that is unless you are just hankering to use it, then these to the same thing.    `switch -regex (([regex]::Match('abcxyzabc', 'abc(?<x>.*)abc')).Groups) { $PSItem {$PSItem | Select-Object Name, Value, Index, Length}}`   and   `switch (([regex]::Match('abcxyzabc', 'abc(?<x>.*)abc')).Groups) {$PSItem {$PSItem | Select-Object Name, Value, Index, Length}}`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Did I miss anything or is `switch -regex` not supposed to give the location of each match?

Indeed, **neither the [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) statement's `-Regex` switch nor the (effectively) underlying

[`-match` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match) are designed to provide information other than what *text* was captured**, via the [automatic `$Matches` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#matches) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57549248/45375) for more information.

Obtaining match-*location* information (start index, length) requires one of the following:

- the [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) cmdlet, as shown in your question.
- direct use of the underlying `[regex]` class ([`System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex)).

Applying the latter to your example:

```sh
PS> [regex]::Match('abcxyzabc', 'abc(?<x>.*)abc')

Groups   : {0, x}
Success  : True
Name     : 0
Captures : {0}
Index    : 0
Length   : 9
Value    : abcxyzabc
```

[Daniel's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68424770/45375) shows you a - somewhat cumbersome - way to provide this functionality via `switch`.

A more efficient approach is to combine a [`foreach` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Foreach) with an `if` statement:

```
foreach ($str in 'abcxyzabc', '...') {
  if     (($match = [regex]::Match($str, 'abc(?<x>.*)abc')).Success) { <# ... #> }
  elseif (($match = [regex]::Match($str, 'cde(?<x>.*)cde')).Success) { <# ... #> }
  # ...
}
```

Comment: Using assignment in `if` looks like the best option I've seen so far. And `if ($s = 'abcxyzabc' | Select-String -Pattern 'abc(?<x>.*)abc')` looks simpler than `[regex]::Match` since it has less pair of parentheses. Just one concern: I've seen debates on whether it's good or not to use assignment in `if` condition in other programming languages, though it makes the code cleaner. I didn't find any debate on it in PowerShell language but I suppose that's the trade off I've to make.

Comment: It also looks weird to me that `Select-String -Pattern` and `[regex]::Match` return the match location information while `switch -regex` and `-match` operator don't as the behavior isn't consistent.

Comment: @Haoshu, as for the inconsistency: PowerShell generally aims for for a higher-level, simplified experience, which often means that simplicity is favored over full access to the underlying .NET functionality (which is still available to those aware of the underlying APIs). That said, you're correct that there's an asymmetry between the `Select-String` cmdlet on the on hand, and the `switch` statement, `-match` operator on the other.

Comment: @Haoshu, as for `'abcxyzabc' | Select-String -Pattern 'abc(?<x>.*)abc'` vs.  `[regex]::Match($str, 'abc(?<x>.*)abc')`: yes, the former is more PowerShell-like, but will perform worse than the latter due to the use of the _pipeline_ and a cmdlet - though that may not matter in practice.

Comment: @Haoshu, as for avoiding the use of assignment as _expressions_, such as in `if` conditionals: I understand that there's potential for confusing between `=` (assignment) and `-eq` (comparison) for _novices_, but to those familiar with the language the ability to use assignments as expressions is a powerful concept that allows for more concise, expressive code.

Answer (score 3):

You could use this ugly alternative which uses the Regex class directly and will give you index and length

```
$values = @(
    'abcxyzabc'
    'cat in the hat'
    'the dogg pound'
)

switch ($values) {
    {($script:myMatches = [regex]::Matches($_, 'abc(?<x>.*)abc'))} {
        $myMatches.Groups[1]
    }
    {($script:myMatches = [regex]::Matches($_, 'cat(?<x>.*)hat'))} {
        $myMatches.Groups[1]
    }
}
```

Results

```
Success  : True
Name     : x
Captures : {x}
Index    : 3
Length   : 3
Value    : xyz

Success  : True
Name     : x
Captures : {x}
Index    : 3
Length   : 8
Value    :  in the
```

Comment: I don't think that's ugly but super hacky lol, you could still use `switch -regex (...)` to make it look cleaner

Comment: Man, all you guys are so smart(:

Comment: Effective, but somewhat cumbersome. It's unfortunate that the branch _condition_ script block (unexpectedly) runs in a _child_ scope, which complicates the solution.

Comment: `switch -Regex ($values) { 'abc(?<x>.*)abc' { [regex]::Matches($_, 'abc(?<x>.*)abc').Groups[1] ...}` would be easier on the eyes, still, this answer is great.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, while definitely easier on the eyes, it's inefficient due to matching the regex twice (though you do also pay a performance penalty simply for using a _script block_ as the condition, which may be worse in practice (haven't tried to measure)).

Comment: @mklement0 Agreed, I would personally use a `foreach loop` like you're doing on your answer but since OP was asking about `switch -Regex` that was my first thought after seeing Daniel's answer.

Comment: I've since realized that `[regex]::Match()` _always_ returns an object, and that it is the `.Success` property that indicates whether a match was found; thus, `($script:myMatches = ...)` should be `($script:myMatches = ...).Success`

Answer (score 2):

Continuing from my comment.

> https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-switch/#Using_the_-RegEx_Parameter
>
> Referencing the code below, the first line will import the contents of
> the RegExp.txt and store it in the $RegExp variable. Then, the
> Powershell switch statement uses the email.txt file as the input for
> test values as indicated by the -file parameter.

```
$RegExp = Get-Content .\RegExp.txt
switch -regex -file .\email.txt {
    $RegExp {"[$_] is an email address"}
    Default {"[$_] is NOT an email address"}
}
```

> Once the code above is run in PowerShell, only the test value that
> matches the regular expression stored in the $RegExp will be
> validated.

> https://riptutorial.com/powershell/example/3791/switch-statement-with-regex-parameter
>
> The -Regex parameter allows switch statements to perform regular
> expression matching against conditions.

```
switch -Regex ('Condition')
{ 
  'Con\D+ion'    {'One or more non-digits'}
  'Conditio*$'   {'Zero or more "o"'} 
  'C.ndition'    {'Any single char.'}  
  '^C\w+ition$'  {'Anchors and one or more word chars.'} 
  'Test'         {'No match'} 
}
```

***Update***

relative to @daniel alternative helpful approach, mixed with your effort; can be refactored to this.

```
switch -regex ('abcxyzabc') 
{
    {($script:myMatches = [regex]::Matches($PSItem, 'abc(?<x>.*)abc'))} 
    {
        $myMatches.Groups | 
        Select-Object Name, Value, Index, Length
    }
} 

# Results
<#
Name Value     Index Length
---- -----     ----- ------
0    abcxyzabc     0      9
x    xyz           3      3
#>
```